# Closest function to $y=x$ while being less than $y=x?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What existing real continuous function less than $y=x$ is closest to $y=x?$ The best I could come up with so far is $y=\sqrt{x}\ln(x).$

How can one invent a real continuous function that is as close as possible to $y=x$ yet still less than $y=x?$

Thanks very much.

Comment: How about $y=x-\varepsilon$?

Comment: What does "close to" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none. If you propose an $f(x)$ I will beat you with $\frac 12(x+f(x))$

Comment: can I change my question to reflect that $f$ must be concave?

Comment: How does that help?  If $f$ is concave then so is $(x+f(x))/2$.

Comment: okay I guess this answers my question